# How to get rows containing both date and "null" with ODATA filter query? (Power Automate)

Tags: oracle, odata, power-automate

I´ve been trying to create some customer reports but I keep getting stuck on trying to retrive rows that matches two arguments.

I need to retrive all rows containing both the OUT_DATETIME where it matches the current date and if the OUT_DATETIME is null. Now I have very little experience with ODATA filter queries but I´ve tried adding "or eq  null" "or OUT_DATETIME eq null" "or null" after the expression without any luck.

This is how the filter query currently look:

[image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/btgiS.png

Comment: Please show in plain text the filter you are expecting, I suspect you are having trouble with OR, you can use brackets in the syntax if it helps, but its not clear what you want to return